# PrintWriter garbled output

Tags: java, io, printwriter

I have the following code

```
    //Put the collection frequencies into a file            
    Iterator iter = docFreq.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry tf = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
        pw.write((String)tf.getKey());
        pw.write("\t");
        pw.write((int)tf.getValue());
        pw.write("\t");
        float fractionofDocs = (int)tf.getValue()/(float)size;
        pw.println(fractionofDocs);
    }

    pw.close();
```

I'm seeing garbled output for the second value written to the file i.e., `pw.write((int)tf.getValue());`

The output is something like this

```
and õ   0.9607843
of  ë   0.92156863
the ê   0.91764706
on  Þ   0.87058824
information Ö   0.8392157
```

I'm able to see the second field printed as an `int` value if the last field is omitted i.e., after removing these lines from `while`

```
pw.write("\t");
float fractionofDocs = (int)tf.getValue()/(float)size;
pw.println(fractionofDocs);
```

Can anyone please tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: `pw.println("" + fractionofDocs);` or `pw.println(String.valueOf(fractionofDocs));` Same for all the other numbers you'r printing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two overloads for `Writer.write` - one which writes a single character, and one which writes a `String`. This is analogous to how `OutputStream.write` writes either a byte or a byte array.

You are calling `Writer.write(int)`, which takes an `int`, converts it to a `char` and writes that `char`.

You want to be using `print` instead of `write`.